# Syntax for including variable in single quoted string

Tags: php

Sorry for the trivial post, but I cannot figure this out on my own.

So I am basically appending a div and I need the `maximum-length` class to have a PHP variable like `maximum-length-$max` but I cannot figure out the syntax I need to use.

I have tried what is done before:   `'.$max.'` ,but this does not work.

```
$addressFields .= '<div style="position: relative"><input type="text" title="'.$this->__('Street Address '.($_i+1)).'" name="billing[street]['.$_i.']" id="billing:street'.($_i+1).'" value="'.$dataHelper->clearDash($this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getStreet($_i+1)).'" class="'.(($_i == 0)? 'required-entry ' : ''). 'input-text validate-address-lenght maximum-length-$max />';
```

Comment: Try this `$addressFields .= '<div style="position: relative"><input type="text" title="'.$this->__('Street Address '.($_i+1)).'" name="billing[street]['.$_i.']" id="billing:street'.($_i+1).'" value="'.$dataHelper->clearDash($this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getStreet($_i+1)).'" class="'.(($_i == 0)? 'required-entry ' : ''). "input-text validate-address-lenght maximum-length-$max\" />";`

Comment: Can you tell us the error you are getting?

Comment: I did fix it. Can you please read the comment to @B. Desai , maybe you know whats going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close `'` before and after you varable. Try following code:

```
$addressFields .= '<div style="position: relative"><input type="text" title="'.$this->__('Street Address '.($_i+1)).'" name="billing[street]['.$_i.']" id="billing:street'.($_i+1).'" value="'.$dataHelper->clearDash($this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getStreet($_i+1)).'" class="'.(($_i == 0)? 'required-entry ' : ''). 'input-text validate-address-lenght maximum-length-'.$max.'" />';
```

Comment: If you can see in the question, I already tried that. This is what is done before, for example `'.($_i+1)).'`, but when I do the same thing in the class all of the following text "inverts"

Comment: Hmmm... this actually does work, but for whatever reason Atom doesnt understand the syntax? It inverts the color as if I had escaped a quote, but on server there are no errors and everything works

Comment: Yep, seems to be Atom thing... Copied it in NP++ and highlighting was a expected

Answer (score 2):

That is one terrible one-liner to read.

I would do the following using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
    $addressFields .= sprintf('
        <div style="position: relative">
            <input type="text"
                    title=%s
                    name="billing[street][%s]"
                    id="billing:street%s"
                    value="%s"
                    class="%s input-text validate-address-lenght maximum-length-%s"
             />',
        $title = $this->__('Street Address ' . ($_i + 1)),
        $name = $_i,
        $id = $_i + 1,
        $value = $dataHelper->clearDash($this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getStreet($_i + 1)),
        $class = ($_i === 0) ? 'required-entry ' : '',
        $max = 'YOUR_MAX_VALUE_HERE'
    );
```

Also shouldn't "validate-address-lenght" be "validate-address-length" in your class values?

Comment: That does look way better, but unfortunately i'm working with  Magento and that just the way it's done there.

Comment: Also, yes, I made the class myself, my english shows I guess